# Multiple Interfaces in Java - what's the syntax?

Tags: java, interface

I want to implement 3 interfaces in my class. I am not sure whether this is even possible, because as far as I know, a class can only inherit from one other class. Do the interfaces behave different?
If they do, how do I implement more then one interface?

I have tried this, but it does not work...

```
public class Container implements InterfaceI implements InterfaceII implements InterfaceIII
{
   //...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Bene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a comma, each time you add one interface and use "implements" only one time. So yes, you can implement more interfaces :D
So it looks like this:

```
public class Container implements InterfaceI, InterfaceII, InterfaceIII
{
   //...
}
```

John

Answer (score 0):

Use your Code like below. Don't use implements multiple time.

```
public class Container implements InterfaceI , InterfaceII ,InterfaceIII
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend one class or abstract class and implement an infinite number of interfaces